# Designing nodejs expressjs mongodb Webserver flow for desktop, mobile native apps and oAuth functionality

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, jwt

I am developing a web server that
1) Provide normal cookie based sessions for desktop browsers
2) Provide JWT for mobile and REST api and some times we can use JWT for browser also
3) In future I have plans to provide OAuth functionality for this server.

Suggest me the way how to identify the request is coming from either desktop browser or native mobile web app or OAuth client

Comment: You could provide a key that is sent to your server on every request, and have it be a different value or format for desktop vs mobile clients.

Answer (score 0):

As for the desktop vs. mobile issue you can take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/358280 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758511/358280

And for the distinction between your jwt tokens and oauth i suggest you take a look at https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/27/ten-things-you-should-know-about-tokens-and-cookies/#token-oauth (section 9).